# Force viewport width between 1024px and 768px on desktop - bootstrap.css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

For reasons unknown, I need the browser to pick up anything between 1024px and 768px and set the width of the viewport to 1024px.

This works on mobile, by changing the viewport using:

```
        var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var viewport = document.getElementsByName("viewport")[0];
        if (viewportWidth >= 1024) {
            viewport.setAttribute("content", "width=1024, initial-scale=.6, maximum-scale=.6");
            return;
        }

        if (viewportWidth >= 768) {
            viewport.setAttribute("content", "width=768, initial-scale=.6, maximum-scale=.6");
            return;
        }
```

Or is there a way to make bootstrap use the large grid and then I scale the site smaller?

Comment: I find it interesting that your code works, since if the browser has a bigger viewport than 1024 it still sets it to 768.

Comment: Is there any way to abuse the site to use the viewport on desktop browsers?

Comment: None that I know of, but why do you need the width of the site to be 1024? If you use bootstrap just set the your `content` tag to a minimum size of 1024?

Comment: the viewport tag is not listened to by desktop browsers. This is my issue. I need the site scaled to 768 width, if its between 768 and 1024

Comment: It is probably listened to, but it doesn't work how you think it does. Basically it just sets the initial size that you would like it to have: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Attributes

This means that if the screen is bigger it will probably be expanded.